# echo names and number of lines for each file in a directory

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am supposed to write a shell script to which I send a command line argument, which represents a directory. Then I am supposed to echo all the filenames and number of lines for each file from that directory. I am also supposed to only do this for the top 10 files not older than 10 minutes.

```
find "$1" -cmin -10 -type f | head -10
```

This is what I tried for finding the files newer than 10 minutes, but I have gotten some errors. And also I am not sure how to get the names. Thanks in advance for all the help.

My file names are free. The error I get is that the permission is denied, when passing my home directory as the argument. So I don't get the list of names. I am supposed to both get the list of filenames and the number of lines of each of those files.

When I type `/bin/bash ss1 /home/ivana` into the terminal, I get the following error:

```
find: '/home/ivana/.cache/dconf': Permission denied
```

I am using Linux.

Comment: What errors? How free are your file names? Do you have some sort of fixed naming scheme or are they free? If the latter, your command will fail for file names with newlines. What do you mean "get the names"? The output of the command you show will be a list of file names. What more is needed? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: My file names are free. The error I get is that the permission is denied, when passing my home directory as the argument. So I don't get the list of names. I am supposed to both get the list of filenames and the number of lines of each of those files.

Comment: OK, please [edit] your question and explain this. Comments are easy to miss, hard to read and can be deleted without warning. Show the *exact* error and also show the *exact* script and the *exact* command you use to call it. There is no way you don't have permission to read your home dir (that would have stopped you from logging in in the first place) so we need more detail.

Comment: Do try a loop(for file in $(command); do; name=$(basename $file .*); echo $name | wc -l; done) and btw |head -10 is taking the 10th file, not the first 10 if I'm right

Comment: @ADDB I tried that and I get the error which I added to my question.

Comment: Make sure your directory and the files in it have read permissions given

Comment: @ADDB eeek! [No, *never* do `for file in $(command)`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: I know, it was just to show what I mean. Normally I would do that kind of loop with an array (Best would be `command` for the loop tho :P [joke])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, first things first. The error you get is irrelevant, it just means that a specific subdirectory (`/home/ivana/.cache/dconf`) of your `$HOME` is not owned by you. This almost certainly happened because you ran a graphical application with `sudo`. The simple fix is:

```
sudo chown -R ivana /home/ivana/
```

That will change the ownership of all files and directories in your `$HOME` back to your own username. If you can have things there that are correctly owned by another user, then just change the ownership of the `dconf` directory:

```
sudo chown -R ivana /home/ivana/.cache/dconf
```

---

Now, that said, the way to do this correctly and deal with arbitrary file names is:

```
find "$1" -cmin -10 -type f -print0 | head -z -n 10
```

That will cause `find` to print each file found with a trailing `\0` instead of a newline, which ensures it will work with files whose names contain newline characters. The `-z` option of `head` makes it read `\0`-delimited input.

The next step is to read each of the files and print the number of lines they have:

```
find "$1" -cmin -10 -type f -print0 | head -z -n 10 |
    while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do wc -l "$file"; done
```

The `IFS=` sets the input field separator to empty, the `-r` makes `read` not treat `\` specially (so `\t` doesn't become a tab) and the `-d ''` tells `read` to read `\0`-delimited data.